# How can I convert ExceptionThrown_V1.ExceptionFlags to a valid C# Enum?

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

Following the .NET documentation on the [.NET runtime exception events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/diagnostics/runtime-exception-events#exceptionthrown_v1-event), I am trying to map the *ExceptionFlags* whose value is `UInt16` to an *Enum*:

```
[Flags]
public enum ExceptionFlags : UInt16
{
    HasInnerException = 0x01,
    IsNestedException = 0x02,
    IsRethrownException = 0x04,
    IsCorruptedException = 0x08,
    IsCLSComplaint = 0x10
}
```

But the values that are coming from the event fall outside the values in the doc. For example I am getting 17 and sometimes 16.

What is the logic to map those values into the flags on the enum?

Comment: To clarify your question, do you already know how a *flags* enum works in general - i.e. are you familiar with how they use powers of 2? You're just not familiar with the `0x` hexadecimal notation?

Comment: I am familiar with how the enum with flags work I just don't know what all the combinations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values preceded by `0x` are [hexadecimal literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals). The equivalent using decimal literals would be:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum ExceptionFlags : UInt16
{
    HasInnerException = 1,
    IsNestedException = 2,
    IsRethrownException = 4,
    IsCorruptedException = 8,
    IsCLSComplaint = 16
}
```

As is typical for an enum marked `[Flags]`, each predefined value is a power of 2. They can be combined together with the bitwise OR `|` to produce values not listed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c) for more details.

Your examples:

- Decimal 16 = Hexadecimal `0x10` = Binary `0001 0000` = `IsCLSComplaint`. This indicates that the exception is CLS compliant, but it doesn't have an inner exception, and it's not a nested, rethrown, or corrupted exception.
- Decimal 17 = Hexadecimal `0x11` = Binary `0001 0001` = `IsCLSCompliant | HasInnerException`. This indicates that the exception is CLS compliant and it has an inner exception, but it's not a nested, rethrown, or corrupted exception.

Comment: So I will need to consruct all the possible combinations and include them on the Enum before I can map the value, correct? That's going to be a pain!

Comment: No, you don't need to include all the possible combinations, just each of the individual flags, as long as each is given a value equal to a power of 2. See the linked answer for more details on how this works.

Comment: Still a bit confused, Given any UInt16, how can I return an ExceptionFlags enum without having to specify the combinations on the enum itself? Let's say I have a method `private bool TryParse(UInt16 value, out ExceptionFlags result)`

Comment: The possible values of an enum variable in C# are not limited to just those specified - the specified values are just named constants that are there for coding and string formatting convenience. In essence, an `ExceptionFlags` value is already an `UInt16` - you can just cast it `(ExceptionFlags) yourUInt16Value`.